# how to loop through Generic Type during compile time in c#

Tags: c#, generics

**T** is known in runtime. But i want to cast **T** into IEnumerable object type during compile time and loop through it.

```
public void x<T>(T obj) 
{
   //T is IEnumerable<object>
   //how to loop through T on compile time? 
}
```

Comment: This looks like a design problem, in short if you know enough to know it will be an `IEnumerable` then your signature should probably reflect that  `public void x<T>(IEnumerable<T> list)`

Comment: @MichaelRandall Thanks for the comment. But sometimes T is not an lEnumerable<object>.sometimes it is a string sometimes it is a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds simple

```
    public void x<T>(T obj)
    {
        //T is IEnumerable<object>
        //how to loop through T on compile time? 
        try
        {
            foreach (var item in (IEnumerable)obj)
            {
                // Do what you want
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Comment: oh thanks. this is what im looking for. Im boxing the object into (List<>)obj and obviously giving me error. forgot to use IEnumerable. I'm having a great time learning c#.net. Thanks